# In SAS which ODS destination is open by default

Tags: sas

There is a question in SAS Base Certification book as below:

```
If ODS is set to its default settings, what types of output are created by:
          ods html file='c:\myhtml.htm';
          ods pdf file='c:\mypdf.pdf';
a. HTML and PDF
b. PDF only
c. HTML, PDF, and listing
d. No output is created because ODS is closed by default.
```

Its answer is 'c', as it mentions that listing is enabled by default. My query here is that is listing or html enabled by default? In the university edition I find HTML as default. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: What version of the certification book are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in the answer key, HTML has been the default installation setting for the last several versions (9.3+) but you can also change that. Seems like a bad question, IMO.

See the update guide, last entry here:

> The correct answer should be "a. HTML and PDF." The explanation is correct.

https://www.sas.com/sas/books/content-updates-base-prep-guide.html